# Should I use language_attributes() or bloginfo("language") in html tag

Tags: theme-development

I heard there is two ways to put the language attribute into the html tag.

The two ways are:

- `<html <?php language_attributes();?>>`
- and `<html lang="<?php bloginfo("language"); ?>">`

Is there a specific coding convention everyone uses or is it a case where its up to the programmer. The reason is because I want my wordpress theme to have proper code according to the coding conventions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `language_attributes()`, it handles [rtl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left) and html or xhtml doctypes, and has a filter that users may want to hook in a child theme.

You can see how they differ in source:

1. [`language_attributes()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L2380)
2. [`get_bloginfo()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L682)

Comment: @Milo When using the language_attributes(), within `<html>`, several errors appears when validating the code, unlike when using `bloginfo('language')`.  Would you say it is a case that `language_attributes()` causes the least issues later on, during website development?